# Android SDK: Xml Pull Parser - How to get the node name

Tags: android, android-xml, xmlpullparser, android-parser

I am using the Xml Pull Parser to parse some Xml from a URL. I'm retrieving the values of the nodes without any problem, however I can't seem to get the node name - it's just returning null.

For example:

```
<ArtistName>Joe</ArtistName>
```

I can retrieve "Joe" but can't get what node "Joe" is from, so instead of returning "ArtistName", it returns null.

Here is my code:

```
public static void getAllXML(String url) throws 
       XmlPullParserException, IOException, URISyntaxException{ 

           Log.i("*****PARSER CALLED******","****PARSER CALLED*****");

         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

         XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser(); 
         String tagName = parser.getName();
         parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(getUrlData(url)));  
         XmlUtils.beginDocument(parser,"EventsPricePoints");
         int eventType = parser.getEventType();
         do{
           XmlUtils.nextElement(parser);
           parser.next();
           String nodeName = parser.getName();
           eventType = parser.getEventType();
           if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT){


             Log.i("************PARSER**********",nodeName+"....."+parser.getText());
           }
         } while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) ;       
       }
```

As you can see, i'm trying to get the node name by using

> parser.getName()

which is returning null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Canche your code to

```
do{ 
   XmlUtils.nextElement(parser);
   parser.next();
   String nodeName;
   eventType = parser.getEventType();
   if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
     if(nodeName!=null) {
       Log.i("************PARSER**********","Last parsed node name="+nodeName+"....."+parser.getText());
     }
   } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
       nodeName = parser.getName()
   }

 } while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) ;
```

Comment: is there no way to get the node name of non start or end tags?

Comment: to @user1417302 You can save last founded node name. I update answer

Comment: unfortunately this still doesn't work, the if(nodeName!=null) never gets called as the variable nodeName must be initialized to null

Comment: at this point nodeName will contain "ArtistName" from XML 

   } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
       nodeName = parser.getName()
   }

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML from:

```
<ArtistName>Joe</ArtistName>
```

to

```
<ArtistName name="ArtistName">Joe</ArtistName>
```

The rest should work as implemented.